# Meta analysis of quantile regressions in a mixed model approach

Tags: mixed-model, meta-analysis, effect-size, quantile-regression

I want to test if lower quantiles lead to lower effect sizes of quantile regressions. The regressions were made across different, nested, contexts. Specifically, I made correlations for 3 percentiles (10th, 50th and 90th), using three different estimates of the response,  coming from 3 different databases, in each of 13 different groups of observations.

Since the reference below indicates that I should use the slope to represent effect size

Geraci, M., & Bottai, M. (2014). Linear quantile mixed models. Statistics and computing, 24(3), 461-479.

I thought I could do:
lmer(Slope~percentile+(1|Tmax)+(1|Group))

But I wonder if that is correct and if I should somehow include the slope's error in the model. Adding it as a fixed factor allows running the model, but I feel it might be an incorrect way to enter the error.

Alternatively, I thought of making a lot of t-tests for slope and error, paired within a combination of database and groups, so that each slope and error are compared within the same group and database among pairs of quantiles.

Would any of the approaches seem valid to test the difference in effect size among quantiles?